# How useState works with eventListener in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, this

In the below sandbox project, I was trying to use a custom hook to attach event listener.

In the useEventListener.js file, If I pass the savedHandler.current function directly to the event listener (line no: 21) I do not get the updated state value during state update. Only when I use the savedHandler.current function inside an anonymous function(line no: 19) I am getting the updated state value.

Could someone help me understand how this works ?
Is this because of this reference?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cloud-kjw7dk?file=/src/useEventListener.js

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to store `handler` in a ref if you are using `useCallback()` that is anyways going to prevent re-render even if it is mentioned in `useEffect()` deps ?

Comment: @PratikWadekar, I need few state values inside the useCallback function
so I am using ref to store the handler function (to prevent re-render in the custom hook), like whenever there is a change in dependency the function is computed again with the latest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I can explain:

For the context, when you click the **toggle flag** button, only your first `useEffect(callback,[handler])` runs after EVERY rendering and your second `useEffect(callback,[eventName,element])` runs ONLY ONCE after the initial rendering.

1. Now when you pass **savedHandler.current** directly to the event listener, line 21, the event listener attaches function returned by `useCallback` as it is and hence on every event, the same function is being called due to **reasons:** The event is registered only ONCE and the cleanup function does not run since the `useEffect` runs only once after the initial rendering(the cleanup function will run in instances, just before the next side effect due to dependency changes, and when the component unmount). So you are registering the event only once with a memoized callback which persist across renderings. The update of **savedHandler.current** in the first `useEffect` doesn't update the callback passed to event listener in the second `useEffect` since it doesn't re-run and hence doesn't update the callback passed to the event listener.
2. Now when you use **savedHandler.current** function inside an anonymous function, the scenario is completely different here. When you pass such functions as a callback, on every event a new function is being invoked unlike the first instance. The anonymous callback of first event and second event is not same despite having the same code. So here you are not stuck with the same event listener callback that you passed previously and hence you have now access to the latest memoized **savedHandler.current** value inside the callback function updated by the first useEffect despite the second effect not running again.

This is it. To confirm for yourself, try to add **handler** as the dependency on your second `useEffect` as well, and pass **savedHandler.current** directly to the event listener. You will get the updated state value as the `useEffect` now runs after every update of **handler** and the event listener gets the latest callback to invoke upon.
And instead of creating another variable, you can directly do `element.addEventListener(eventName, (event) => savedHandler.current(event));`

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation , now I am able to wrap my head around this.
I thought since ref works based on reference, the updated function should be called each time, Even if we pass the ref directly to the eventHandler.
Just one small doubt, like you said the anonymous function will be diff during each event trigger, then how will the eventListener will be removed? Since we need to pass the same reference of function in add and remove listeners.

Comment: You'r welcome. You can keep the code as it is if you want to pass same function in add and remove event listeners, the one where you store the anonymous function in a variable and use it as a reference in both the add and remove listeners which will be same since they both now point to the same anonymous function. Just like how a variable can be used multiple times once defined as they all point to the same value, and if updated/changed all other values point to the updated/changed value and are all equal.